# Rails form to edit API call based on date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

I'm trying to build a form that will allow a user to edit an API call for search date. The idea is to allow a person to search for near earth asteroids in a given time window by calling one of NASA's APIs. Not really sure where to start to figure this one out.

Here is the call in my model. You can see start_date and end_date,` which I want to edit based on user information

```
class Astroid < ApplicationRecord

def self.get_api_info
    astroid = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2017-03-15&end_date=2017-03-15&api_key=*****"                                                                                               
    request_to_astroid = Net::HTTP.get(URI(astroid))
    JSON.parse request_to_astroid

end
```

end

Here is my very simple controller

```
def index
@astroid_info = AstroidApi.get_api_info
```

end

And the view I want to show after gathering a user's date selection

```
 <%= @astroid_info['near_earth_objects']["2017-03-15"][1]["close_approach_data"][0]["close_approach_date"]%> an astroid named <%= @astroid_info ['near_earth_objects']["2017-03-15"][1]["name"] %> missed us by: <%= @astroid_info ['near_earth_objects']["2017-03-15"][0]["close_approach_data"][0]["miss_distance"]["miles"] %>
```

Here's the link to see how the data is given: https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2017-03-15&end_date=2017-03-15&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: My initial thought is to replace the start_date and end_date with variables populated from user input. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this as I'm not sure how I would successfully edit the model after gaining this information

Answer (score 0):

I will say right off the bat I am not extremely familiar with Ruby or Rails. However, I might be able to lead you in some direction or try to confirm your thoughts. When you make an API call you have the chance to decide what data to send with the call. By building a form with dates that the user can select, you could then pull the input values from that form to send with your call.

You can use date picker input like such:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="date-selection">Date:</label>
  <input type="date" name="date-selection">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or use two of these to create a date range to search, by adding another date input.
Then grab the input from this to send with your API call. Sorry I can't help you with pulling the data from the input for your call, I write in JS (for the time being).

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
@start_date = params[:start_date]
@end_date = params[:end_date]
@astroid_info = Astroid.get_api_info["element_count"]
@astroid_date = Astroid.get_api_info["near_earth_objects"]
```

View:

```
    <%= form_tag searchApi_path, method: "get", html: { class: "form" } do %>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= text_field_tag(:start_date, "", placeholder: "Enter date", class: "form-control") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:end_date, "", placeholder: "Enter date", class: "form-control") %>
</div>

<div class= 'container'>
<%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-success"  %>
<% end %>
```